Netbeans 21 and .mjs- filetype
I just installed Netbeans V21 and saw that .mjs- files are not recognized by the spellchecker, even after importing the setup from V20.
Then I opened Tools/ Options/ Miscellaneous/ Files and set "File extension" to mjs and the "Associated File Type ( Mime )" to text/javascript and the sourcecode is still not "recognized" as such.
What else do I have to do to make Netbeans recognize .mjs- files' sourcecode?

So the easy answer seems to be that Netbeans 21 does not take this change without a restart as Netbeans 20 did.
Restarting made the IDE use the chosen spellchecker.
